# Lots of unaccounted for IO writes

Tags: io, nginx, centos

i run a webserver with CentOS 5.7. It runs nginx and php-fpm. I run a busy website (500k unique a day) on it. Not many files are created on this server, maybe 20 per minute, and all small files of a few KB.

Running `iotop` and `iostat` I noticed that I am having A LOT of io writes, way more than reads.

iostat - > http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=YHtDSTSP
iotop -> http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=yiAyhSbP

It shows that Nginx Worker Processes are doing most of the writes. But I do not understand what nginx has to write so much for. Up to 15MB per second sometimes.

I have set:

```
access_log              off;
error_log              /var/log/nginx.log crit;
```

I also checked all other logs in /var/log, nothing that is accounting for this many writes.

Any idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it by really disabling the access log.